# Spring Logback + SLF4j

Tags: spring, slf4j

I have a spring rest service project in which I am trying to log the sql queries and parameters which is not working for me (I am not even getting the queries). Listed below is the pom configuration and the logback.xml

POM.xml

```
<!-- Logging Starts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyyddMM:HHmmss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.home}/logs/application.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.home}/logs/application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyyddMM:HHmmss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="DEBUG" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.home}/logs/application_debug.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>./application_debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyyddMM:HHmmss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <!-- logger name="com.base22" level="TRACE"/ -->
    <logger name="com.application." level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="org.apache" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="java.sql" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="jdbc.audit" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="jdbc.connection" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="jdbc.resultset" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
     <logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="TRACE" />
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUG" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: where did you put your XML file?  How do you call the logger in the class?

Comment: logback.xml is in src/main/resources and I call the logger in the class file as private static final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(classname.class)

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49568780/4369820